# Matrix of matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to build up the matrix of matrices. Say, for all `$1\leq i,j\leq n$` I have to define a matrix `$p_{ij}$` which will be a matrix `$n\times n$`. What I can do - it is to build up a matrix `$P$` which is `$n^2\times n^2$` - but for `$n=20$` there is an error about memory.

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: how to type math formulas here, ins't LaTeX supported?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [cell](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html) arrays. Like this

```
c = cell(3,3) %Create cell array of size *3x3*

c = 

    []    []    []
    []    []    []
    []    []    []

c{1,1}; = rand(3,3); %Set cell {1,1} to be random matrix of size *3x3*
c{1,2} = ones(4,6)   %Set cell {1,2} to be matrix of ones size *4x6*

c = 

    [3x3 double]    [4x6 double]    []
              []              []    []
              []              []    []
```

etc..

Comment: How do I call for element k,l of matrix in the cell i,j?

Comment: @Gortaur: Like this, c{i,j}(k,l)

Comment: @draks Because cell arrays don't have to be be stored in a contiguous memory block and numerical arrays do. So even though cell arrays have larger overhead and require a bit more memory than numerical arrays, you can usually store more information in them.

Comment: @Ghaul cool thanks that's very goog to know. _at_MATLAB Why doesn't Matlab use that internally?